# How to create custom widget like this?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-button

I would like create a custom widget.

It looks like this:
[image]

So, should I extend `Button` because I would like to click on it ?

How can I put an image on it? 
I already read about method `onDraw()`, but I don't know how to put an `image`.

(Thank Andrew T.)

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523232/inflate-into-this/22680619?noredirect=1#comment34621831_22680619

Comment: You should create a LinearLayout with the desired layout and use it to build your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make it a compund object: it's a TextView with a drawable on a side.

TextViews are clickable, so you can fire a click handler.

Something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:text="Title\nA little description for this object"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:onClick="click_handler"
/>
```

Then just add to your code:

```
public void click_handler(View v)
{
    // Do something in your click event
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, for this object, i will use your help, it exactly what i searched

Comment: It's considered a **best practice**, to flatten your design (and gain performance).

Answer (score 0):

Put everything on a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout (An ImageView, two TextViews). Add click listener to that layout. Later you can use the layout in ListViews for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            ......
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ......
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ......
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And then write a class to handle it